# How can I attach sources for a jar library from a folder in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, jar, android-studio, android-debug

I have a jar library in my project in Android Studio and I received the source files for it in a zip file which I need to debug through now. The problem is, that I am not able to load these sources from the zip file or from an unzipped folder. My library is in `app/libs` and I saved the source files to `app/src/external_libs`.

The IDE shows "sources not found" and provides an 'Attach Sources' button, but I am not able to use it: It allows me to select the folder, I even manage to get to the'Choose Roots' screen, but after pressing OK, nothing happens.

[image]

I also tried *File -> Project Structure ->Dependencies -> Add* but then Gradle alerts that it only accepts jar files.

1. How can I attach the source files from an actual folder?
2. There is possibility that the files I was given are not on the exact same version as the jar. Could this be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing the same issue here: had a .jar library and its sources, and want to attach the sources to Android Studio, so when I ctrl+click on any method from the library it shows it source in the editor. To do so, you have to select the root of the sources directory uncompressed using the "Attach Sources..." or "Choose Sources..." link (or button) you saw in the upper right corner of the editor.

That's for your question number 1, for the number 2, I think that it is not a problem for the attach mechanism, but definitively for the coherence of the code in the editor.

Hope this helps you or someone.

Comment: Android studio 2.2.3, could not find "Attach Sources..".

Answer (score -1):

Follow the below Steps in android studio ->

File -> New Module -> pop up window will open -> select import jar or aar as shown in attached image -> another popup window will open -> Now select our jar file from your folder and done.[image]